# ROR:How to copy data in a table from one database to other table in which is in another database which has different table attributes in heroku?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, heroku-postgres

I have Products table with col_1, col_2, col_3 as attributes in one database and in another database I have products table with product_name, product_price, product_count. How can I copy or move data from col_1 to Product_price and col_2 to product_name in Heroku.

Comment: how are you connecting to the 2 databases?

Comment: Im not connecting databases....is it possible to do with pg db backup

Answer (score 0):

I have many questions on your setup but I will take a stab at this.

in my model "Products"

```
# app/models/product.rb
Class Product < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  after_create :propagate_to_db2
  ...
  private
  def propagate_to_db2
     #connect_to_db2
      sql = "INSERT INTO products ( 'Product_price', 'product_name' )
      VALUES
      (#{col_1}, #{col_2})"
     #execute sql
  end
end
```

If I had a better understanding in your system I could probably do more but I hope that this helps

Comment: is it possible to move data by taking postgres database backup